# How to find median of a column in R

Tags: r, csv, data-analysis, median

I am trying to find the median of the `weight` column in [this sample csv file](https://hbiostat.org/data/repo/diabetes.csv) using `R`. But the code returns nothing. Where is the problem?

```
diabets <- read.csv ("https://hbiostat.org/data/repo/diabetes.csv")
median (diabets$weight)
```

And then after finding the median, I need to print the females whose weights are lower than this median. How can I do that?

Please NO extra libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`na.rm = TRUE` argument will find median ignoring `NA`'s
There is one `NA` in weights.

```
sum(is.na(diabetes$weight))
[1] 1
```

And `median(diabetes$weight, na.rm = TRUE)` returns 172.5 so,

```
diabetes[diabetes$gender== "female" & diabetes$weight < 172.5, ]
```

will print females whose weights are lower than this median.

## add

```
med <- median(diabetes$weight, na.rm = TRUE)
diabetes[(diabetes$gender== "female" & diabetes$weight < med), ]
```

or

```
diabetes[(diabetes$gender== "female" & diabetes$weight < median(diabetes$weight, na.rm = TRUE)), ]
```

Comment: The median looks good. But when I add that line to print the ones less than 172.5, it also prints the ones bigger than that and male! Weird.
`6    1008  248       94  69   3.6  4.81 Buckingham  34   male     71    190`

Comment: Here is the code:
`diabetes <- read.csv ("https://hbiostat.org/data/repo/diabetes.csv")
diabetes[diabetes$gender== "female" && diabetes$weight < 172.5, ]`

Comment: @TinaJ I'm really sorry. Only one `&` had to be in code. `diabetes[diabetes$gender== "female" & diabetes$weight < 172.5, ]`. I edit my code and I apologize for confusion.

Comment: Cool works now. And how can I pass the median var instead of specifying 172.5 explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

diabets %>% 
  filter(gender == "female") %>% 
  filter(weight < median(weight, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 123 x 19
      id  chol stab.glu   hdl ratio glyhb location    age gender height weight frame bp.1s bp.1d
   <int> <int>    <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <int> <chr>   <int>  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
 1  1000   203       82    56  3.60  4.31 Buckingh~    46 female     62    121 medi~   118    59
 2  1024   242       82    54  4.5   4.77 Louisa       60 female     65    156 medi~   130    90
 3  1030   238       75    36  6.60  4.47 Louisa       27 female     60    170 medi~   130    80
 4  1031   183       79    46  4     4.59 Louisa       40 female     59    165 medi~    NA    NA
 5  1036   213       83    47  4.5   3.41 Louisa       33 female     65    157 medi~   130    90
 6  1271   228       66    45  5.10  4.61 Buckingh~    24 female     61    113 medi~   100    70
 7  1277   179       80    92  1.90  4.18 Buckingh~    41 female     72    118 small   144   112
 8  1282   254       84    52  4.90  4.52 Buckingh~    43 female     62    145 medi~   125    70
 9  1317   136       81    51  2.70  4.58 Buckingh~    22 female     66    160 large   105    85
10  1321   218       68    46  4.70  3.89 Buckingh~    52 female     62    170 medi~   142    79
# ... with 113 more rows, and 5 more variables: bp.2s <int>, bp.2d <int>, waist <int>,
#   hip <int>, time.ppn <int>
```

Comment: I can't use extra libraries.

Comment: You can also keep stacking filters instead of calling the function multiple times - `diabets %>% filter(gender == "female", weight < median(weight, na.rm = TRUE))`